# Convert json to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node and javascript. Sorry if this is an obvious question.

I retrieve data from mysql using the node,js code below:

```
     var quer = connection.query('select password from users where  mail="'+ so +'" ',function(err, result, fields){

               console.log(result);

        });
```

`Result` is this

```
    [{password:'123456'}]
```

I want to get it as only 123456, how can I achieve that?

Comment: `result` is an array that contains an object with a password, it's not JSON. So `console.log(result[0].password)` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

```
console.log(result[0].password)
```